# Counting number of lines in file and saving it in a bash file

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to loop through all the files in a folder and add the file name of those files with 10 lines to a txt file but I don't know how to write the if statement.

As of right now, what I have is:

`for FILE in *.txt do if wc $FILE == 10; then "$FILE" >> saved_names.txt fi done`

I am getting stuck in how to format the statement that will evaluate to a boolean for the if statement.

I have already tried the if statement as:

`if [ wc $FILE != 10 ]`

`if "wc $FILE" != 10`

`if "wc $FILE != 10"`

as well as other ways but I don't seem to get it right. I know I am new to Bash but I can't seem to find a solution to this question.

Comment: `if [ "$(wc -l < $FILE)" -eq 10 ]`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems in your code.

- To count the number of lines in the file you should run "wc -l" command. However, that command will result in the number of lines and the name of the file (so for example - 10 a.txt - you can test it by running the command on a file in your terminal). To receive only the number of lines you need to pass the file's name to the standard input of that command
- "==" is used in bash to compare strings. To compare integers as in that case, you should use "-eq" (take a look here https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)
- In terms of brackets: To get the wc command result you need to run it in a terminal and switch the command in the code to the result. To do that, you need correct brackets - $(wc -l). To receive a result of the comparison as a bool, you need to use square brackets with spaces [ 1 -eq 1 ].
- To save the name of the file in another file using >> you need to first put the name to the standard output (as >> redirect the standard output to the chosen place). To do that you can just use the echo command.

The code should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *.txt
do
  if [ "$(wc -l < "$FILE")" -eq 10 ]
  then
    echo "$FILE" >> saved_names.txt
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    if [[ $(wc -l < "$file") -eq 10 ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$file"
    fi
done > saved_names.txt
```

Change `>` to `>>` if you want to append the filenames.

Related docs:

- [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
- [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the actual number of lines from a file with `wc -l $FILE | cut -f1 -d' '` and use `-eq` operator:

```
for FILE in *.txt; do if [ "$(wc -l $FILE | cut -f1 -d' ')" -eq 10 ]; then "$FILE" >> saved_names.txt; fi; done
```